# How to solve "this is undefined" after mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a custom API to fetch data. I have an object that contains each data to be fetched, so everything is dynamic. At the point had to fetch data using the **fetch()** function. Now a request is been made when the component is mounted (componentDidMount). Since I'm using an object to fetch for each Json data, I'll have to map this object.

```
componentDidMount(){
    CATEGORIES.map(function(category){
        this.fetchApiData(category.key);
    });
}
```

Now I have defined my **fetchApiData()** properly. It actually works without mapping but doesn't when I map the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access `this` inside of another function which does not have access to fetchApiData property. To use the enclosing context, use fat-arrow based function:

```
componentDidMount(){
    CATEGORIES.map((category) => {
        this.fetchApiData(category.key);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well … that's a game of spot-the-difference. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: @Quentin the arrow function keeps the context bound to `this`, the original questions uses a normal function which does not.

Comment: Surprisingly worked! Thanks @Blake

Comment: @Oluwatobiloba You can check out some examples here to learn more: http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis

Answer (score 0):

The context of this changes inside the map's callback function. You can assign this to a variable and use that inside the map's callback function.

```
componentDidMount(){
    var that = this;
    CATEGORIES.map(function(category){
        that.fetchApiData(category.key);
    });
}
```